# EC.presence_of_element_located not and WebDriverWait leads to "Other element would receive the click: ..." error in selenium for Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait, expected-condition

Navigating through web pages (https://www.hertz.com/rentacar/location) rendered through JS. Putting `time.sleep(random.randint(5, 10))` leads to successful clicking of element, while my `waiter` function(shown below) leads to `Other element would receive the click:` error.

The script scrapes every Hertz location in every city in every state in the United States successfully using the `time.sleep` before every selection and click but I believe this to be bad practice and because of the sleeps it takes numerous hours to complete.

full error text:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
Element <a href="javascript: void(0);" id="CO" name="states">...</a> is not clickable at point (518, 9). Other element would receive the click: <li>...</li>
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.157)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

element HTML (this happens on other similar elements)

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" id="CO" name="states">
        <span class="icons-ft_arrow_right"></span> 
    Colorado
    </a>
</li>
```

In my `waiter` function, I have replaced `presence_of_element_located` with:
`visibility_of_element_located`
`element_to_be_clickable`

and received the same error.

I have also tried

`.send_keys(selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.SPACE)`

instead of

`.click()`

to no avail

here is my `waiter` function

```py
def waiter(driver, id=None, class_name=None, link_text=None, name=None, timeout=8):
    if id is not None:
        by = By.ID
        selector = id

    elif class_name is not None:
        by = By.CLASS_NAME
        selector = class_name

    elif name is not None:
        by = By.NAME
        selector = name

    else:
        by = By.LINK_TEXT
        selector = link_text
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((by, selector))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
        return driver
    except TimeoutException:
        time.sleep(300)
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        try:
            element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((by, selector))
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
            return driver
        except TimeoutException:
            print(f"Timed out waiting for {selector} to load")
            raise ValueError('Page is fucked?')
```

This works

```
    time.sleep(random.randint(5, 10))
    directory_link = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ld-tab')
    directory_link.click()
```

This does not

```
    waiter(driver, class_name='ld-tab')
    directory_link = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ld-tab')
    directory_link.click()
```

I would expect my waiter function to successfully make sure the element is clickable without the potential time wasting/unreliability of the sleep functions. Alas, no such reality.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like inside your waiter function you first look for element, then wait.

```
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((by, selector))
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
```

Try swapping places and wait for element first.

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by, selector)))`

Is this what you mean?